# Boto3 S3 Bucket Lifecycle Policy - Delete folders and files after so many days

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a use case where I need to remove content from S3 buckets after 30 days without question. Using Boto3 I'd like to set a lifecycle policy on the S3 bucket itself to clear out the files and folders rather than having to manually run a script every so often. I've looked through the S3 documentation and I'm not seeing where the content can actually be specified to be deleted. I see where I can transfer that content to different storage tiers but that's it.

I'm referring to the documentation here:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.BucketLifecycle.put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that documentation the "Expiration" and "NoncurrentVersionExpiration" are the actions that delete content (whereas "Transition"/"NoncurrentVersionTransition" are the ones to transition objects to a different storage, so you shouldn't include them in the configuration). The "Prefix" then identifies the objects to delete.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. I had wondered about those actions but figured there might be something else to it. Thank you